# Not able to understand random.sample(range(1,40),3)) with sum(1<<i for i in random.sample(range(1,40),3))

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm, mutation, genetic-programming, crossover

I am trying to debug this piece of code and learn a little. I learn that it generates 3 unique values for `i` but how come the values of `sum` become this much big?

If I run it and debug it, it goes something like this. It keep changes since values are chosen randomly.

`i = 6`
`i = 26`
`i = 38`

`test_num = 274945015872`

**Output:**
`100000000000100000000000000000001000000`

Why the value for `test_num 274945015872`? It then uses this value to generate `39-bit` binary string. Like how?

Can someone explain?

**Here is the code:**

```
test_num = sum(1<<i for i in random.sample(range(1,40),3))
#left to right one bit shifting
print (print (f"{test_num:039b}"))
```

Comment: Just to note, you can use `random.seed` to share a persistent result.

Comment: If the values of `i` were 6, 26, and 38, the result is a number with the 6th, 26th, and 38th bits set (counting from the right).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how addition works ...

```
  0b1000           8
+ 0b0100         + 4
---------       -----
  0b1100           12
```

each `1<<N` creates an integer that has a binary value with exactly 1 '1' and the rest zero

suming them sets all the one bits (a integer with 3 distinct bits set to '1')  if your indexes happen to be [0,1,2] you end up with the smallest possible value of `0b111` (7) but there are 40 total position 0..39 so it would be rare to get [0,1,2] as your output

as pointed out in the comments the `sum` can be replaced with

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x|y ,[i for i in ...])
```

this works because when you have a guarantee of distinct one positions NUMERIC ADDITION and BITWISE OR are identical operations

Comment: In other words, bitwise OR can be done using addition if the 1 bits are known to be distinct.

Comment: @JoranBeasley This is incredible. The code was originally posted by you while answering a query. I was so much into it. You rock!

Comment: lol yeah :P I recognized it ...